# How to scale a tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I would like to enlarge a diagram made with the `\graph` command, because the arrows at the current scale look too short to me. The options I have tried, however, seem to have no effect. I have tried `scale`, `sibling distance`, `node distance`, `node sep`, `level distance`, and possibly others. I am compiling with LuaTeX. I have a feeling I am missing something simple. I would just like to magnify it, similar to what the `scale` option would do to other tikz pictures.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees,graphs}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees,force}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\[ 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[clockwise=7,math nodes, edges = {double equal sign distance, -implies}] { "p_1", "p_2", "p_3", "p_4", "p_5", "p_6", "p_7"; "p_1" -> "p_2" -> "p_3" -> "p_4" -> "p_5" -> "p_6" -> "p_7" -> "p_1" }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

This is the current output:

[image: arrows very short]

Thank you!

Comment: `\begin{tikzpciture}[scale=<factor>]...` ?

Comment: Don't put `tikzpicture` inside `\[...\]`!

Comment: @cfr I tried `[scale=<factor>]`... It didn't work in this case. :(

Comment: @cfr Within what should I put tikzpicture instead?

Comment: Don't put it inside anything or, if you want to centre it, put it inside a `center` environment.

Comment: @cfr OK, but, just out of curiosity, what is wrong with putting it inside `\[...\]`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. It is not mathematics. Even if some of the content is maths, you'd still need to switch to maths mode within the picture to typeset that particular content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the option `radius=<value>` to the `\graph` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees,graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees,force}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph[clockwise=7,radius=3cm,math nodes, edges = {double equal sign distance, -implies}] { "p_1", "p_2", "p_3", "p_4", "p_5", "p_6", "p_7"; "p_1" -> "p_2" -> "p_3" -> "p_4" -> "p_5" -> "p_6" -> "p_7" -> "p_1" }; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! "Radius" is an option I didn't even know could be used in `\graph`! Thanks again!!

Comment: @AnthonyPulido The /graph drawing/`radius` key is documented: section 27.11 "Miscellaneous Options", p.396, pgfmanual v3.0.1a.